# The Rails Way - Namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces

I have a question about how to do something "The Rails Way". With an application that has a public facing side and an admin interface what is the general consensus in the Rails community on how to do it?

Namespaces, subdomains or forego them altogether?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There's no real "Rails way" for admin interfaces, actually - you can find every possible solution in a number of applications. DHH has implied that he prefers namespaces (with HTTP Basic authentication), but that has remained a simple implication and not one of the official Rails Opinions.

That said, I've found good success with that approach lately (namespacing + HTTP Basic). It looks like this:

routes.rb:

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.resources :users
  admin.resources :posts
end
```

admin/users_controller.rb:

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :admin_required
  # ...
end
```

application.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # ...

  protected
  def admin_required
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |user_name, password|
      user_name == 'admin' && password == 's3cr3t'
    end if RAILS_ENV == 'production' || params[:admin_http]
  end
end
```

The conditional on `authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic` triggers the HTTP Basic auth in production mode or when you append `?admin_http=true` to any URL, so you can test it in your functional tests and by manually updating the URL as you browse your development site.

Comment: I hate this. The routes get awkward names like this: "new_admin_user_path". It's an operation for an admin to create a new user, not to create a new admin user. It should be called "admin_new_user_path". Ugly. It makes me suspect that I am using namespaces for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 5):

In some smaller applications I don't think you need to separate the admin interface. Just use the regular interface and add admin functionality for logged in users.

In bigger projects, I would go with a namespace. Using a subdomain doesn't feel right to me for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone that answered my question. Looks like the consensus is to use namespaces if you want to as there is no DHH sponsored Rails Way approach. :)

Again, thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Its surely late for a reply, but i really needed an answer to this question: how to easily do admin areas?

Here is what can be used these days: [Active Admin](http://activeadmin.info/), with [Ryan Bates's great intro](http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin).