# Module name scopes in routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I have an intranet application with several modules, I want them to separate when routing. For example:

```
 http://intranet/calendar/...
 http://intranet/site_admin/...
 http://intranet/tasks/...
```

Each of module can have many or single controller. How to write such routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using namespaces:

```
map.namespace :calendar do |calendar|
  calendar.resources :first_controller
  calendar.resources :second_controller
end
```

And so on. Very often people put admin part of application in admin namespace (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119197/the-rails-way-namespaces)). Try google "rails namespace".

Answer (score 0):

Also if you may want to upgrade to the latest version i.e Rails 2.3. And build those modules as separate 'Engines'. http://railscasts.com/episodes/149-rails-engines