# Admin-page login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin

I am a newbie to rails and want to implement a secure admin login page to my site. In order to make it secure I want to make a cookie file and put in on the machine that an administrator will use, so that the app can check for the presence of that cookie and redirect to the admin page where he can enter the password and login.

Thanks
Vishal

Comment: You need to read more. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ . Go through sessions management in rails. Also take a look at authlogic and devise , gems to understand how sessions in rails work

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Admin namespace. Check out the answer for the similar question: [The Rails Way - Namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119197/the-rails-way-namespaces)